# Terminal Manipulating and creating newlines between two lines

Tags: python

I am trying to get input while giving out an output currently I am using ANSI escape codes to do this however I am currently stuck because of the way that new line works. I need to insert a new line between the input line and the previous message but if I use newline it just goes to the next line and doesn't create a newline until the bottom which is where I am getting the user input. For example

```py
import threading

def testing():
  while True:
    time.sleep(1)
    print("\x1b[1ATesting\n")

def getting_userinput():
  while True: 
    #Imagine 12 is the final row of the terminal
    input("\x1b[12;0HThe goodstuff here: ")
inputthread = threading.Thread(target=getting_userinput)
outputthread = threading.Thread(target=testing)
inputthread.start()
outputthread.start()
#Also assume that the cursor returns to the appropriate position.
```

The issue here is that the newline would invade the space of the input line which is at the
bottom and would not insert a blank line between the line where the testing text is and the
The goodstuff input text. So I have though of two solutions the first copying what is on
the line where the input text is and clear it and print the next message and copy the saved
text onto the newly created line at the bottom. The second one is to have a list of all of
the messages and then have them displayed in using cursor commands over hte terminal
however I lose the ability to see the history of the entire program. Does anyone have a
solution for such a problem

Comment: Just so you know, calling input will block the entire Python process, so you'll have problems getting it to work as 'imagined' in the comment.

Comment: Use the `curses` module.